# Use cases for PHP functions "first_" and "next_" versus "get_" for LDAP attributes, values, entries etc

Tags: php, ldap, traversal

The PHP LDAP library defines several classes of functions for traversing the results of a search, the "first/next" functions and the "get" functions:

- `ldap_first_entry`
- `ldap_next_entry`
- `ldap_get_entries`

and so on for attributes, values etc.

What are some use cases for each of these (iterating over each result vs. getting all results in a multidimensional array), and which is the simpler to code for?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to any database, if you expect to receive a lot of results, iterating one result at a time will be preferred. The alternative, fetching all results at once, is convenient but can cause high memory usage if hundreds of results are returned.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of areas in PHP that offer similar pairs of functionality.

For example, `file_get_contents()` vs `fopen()` and `fread()`. Or `XMLReader` vs `SimpleXML`.

In all cases, the main difference between them is that one option loads the entire data structure into memory at once, and the other allows you to load them one at a time as you iterate through the data.

These LDAP functions are the same.

Loading them all into memory at once is quicker, and has advantages if you want to do more than just a simple iteration through a list.

On the other hand, loading them one at a time clearly has advantages with memory usage, particularly if you have a lot of items to read.

PHP gives you the choice because both options have their merits. Use whichever suits your application.

Hope that helps.

Comment: It looks like PHP just mirrors all [the C library functions](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ldap_next_attribute) here.